# finding the area of mutual

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

[image]

What I need to do is to find out the area of the shaded regions.
And also how to get the area of the reason where three circle are mutually  intersected. Do I have to make a triangle inside the mutual intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The area of the shaded region in the given picture is equal to the area of the shaded region in this picture.

[image]

Comment: How to get the intersection area?

Comment: You must use the two pieces of information you were given in order to solve the problem. The intersection area is not relevant.

Comment: So the answer is $40 - 15 =25$ ?

Comment: Right idea, wrong answer. Check that calculation.

Comment: There you go! That's all there is to it!